# Toggle class on direct children

Tags: jquery, children

I have several divs with the same class. I want to be able to toggle the class on the children of each independently on a click function.

```
if($("div").hasClass("subLinkPage")) {
    $(".sub-expand_collapse").children(".fa").toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
}
```

What do I add to this script so it only runs on the immediate children of each.

Thanks for any suggestions

HTML

```
  <div class="subLinkPage"> 
    <ul aria-labelledby="headLnk_02" class="nav__items">
        <li class="sub_p01 togSubList">

             <a role="button" href="#" class="sub-expand_collapse" aria-label="toggle menu">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

            <a id="subLnk_01" class="parent_link menu_p01" href="../content/m04/m04_c02_p01.html">Facebook feed</a>            
            <ul class="sub_items sub_items_01">
                <li><a href="../content/m04/m04_c02_p01-a.html" class="menu_p01a">Adding a Facebook feed<br/>to the home page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub_p02 togSubList">


            <a role="button" href="#" class="sub-expand_collapse" aria-label="toggle menu">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

            <a id="subLnk_02" class="parent_link menu_p02" href="../content/m04/m04_c02_p02.html">Twitter feed</a>            
            <ul class="sub_items sub_items_02">
                <li><a href="../content/m04/m04_c02_p02-a.html" class="menu_p02a">Adding a Twitter<br/>feed web part</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some html structure, and it's not so clear on which element you would like to check the "click" event.

Comment: There are no `.fa` elements that aren't immediate children of `.sub-expand_collapse`. Which elements is it toggling that it shouldn't?

Comment: Adding the HTML isn't enough. What element are you clicking on, and which elements should be toggled when you click, and which elements should *not* be toggled?

Comment: I'm going to have to re-think this and update the post details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the immediate child jQuery [selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) `(parent > child)`

```
$("div.subLinkPage").on('click', function() {
  $(this).find(".sub-expand_collapse > .fa").toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
});
```

Comment: You guys are really helping me think this through

Comment: You don't need `.filter`, just use the selector `$("div.subLinkPage")`

Answer (score 0):

If it's inside a `.click` event, use `$(this)` instead of `$(".sub-expand_collapse")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like `$("MyElement > MyElementsChild").remove();`

The ">" states that it's a child element.

Comment: This still affects all children where .sub-expand_collapse is applied

Comment: @LaurenceL The `>` CSS operator only matches immediate children, not all children. This should work. Please update your question with the HTML, and explain clearly which elements you want to be affected.

Comment: No problem will do that now